# Automate identifying location of flaws

Tags: windows, automation, video-editing

[avidemux](/questions/tagged/avidemux) allows you to mark the start and end and then to delete unwanted frames

This is a most time consuming procedure because the software does not of itself find the "next flawed frame".  Most of mine are  noticed by sudden light changes (white frames instead of a picture ) and so should be found by the software and not by me watching an entire film.

I happen to use Windows and "Lightworks" and "Movie Maker" but the problem exists on all platforms. Take old 8mm films - they had many a "flaw" in them. Current software allows you to cut the flaws out, but you need to see hours and hours of film and stop hen you spot a flaw. THAT should be automated.

Comment: Interesting – but what software are you asking about now? What OS should it run on, what features should it have, what is your price limit when it comes to paid software?

Comment: Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: Izzy - I am 80 years old and find this too complicated to comprehend.  So please help me rather than tell me that it needs changing.  I happen to use Windows and "Lightworks" and "Movie Maker" but the problem exists on all platforms.  Take old 8mm films - they had many a "flaw" in them. Current software allows you to cut the flaws out, but you need to see hours and hours of film and stop hen you spot a flaw.   THAT should be automated irrespective of which software you use

Comment: David, I think my first comment was clear enough. Thanks for the clarification you've provided (I've integrated that with your post and will re-open it now). Could you please add how much money you're willing to spend in case of paid solutions?